# как разбить два столбца на две строки по id

Tags: sql

```
select
case_id,
a.id_police,
c.sign_date,
d.sign_date as sign_date2,
d.id_condition,
e.id_condition as id_condition2
--occurr_date,
--row_number() over (partition by a.id_police  order by d.sign_date desc) as nums, 
--dateadd("yyyy", 0, getdate()) as ourDate
from loss.tbl_Insurance_Cases a 
join loss.tbl_Occurrences b on a.occurr_id = b.occurr_id
join tbl_policies c on a.id_police = c.id_police
left join tbl_Agreements d on a.id_police  = d.id_police
join tbl_InsuranceConditions e on c.id_conditions = e.id_condition


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT0rw.png
```

Comment: Приведите пример желаемого результата. Пока вопрос непонятен.

Comment: @ВикторКарев https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT0rw.png - нужно чтобы (case_id 2712 id_condition 3183) (case_id 2712 1935)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте UNION. Один раз берите одну колонку, второй - другую.

```
select
case_id,
a.id_police,
c.sign_date,
d.sign_date as sign_date2,
d.id_condition,
from loss.tbl_Insurance_Cases a 
join loss.tbl_Occurrences b on a.occurr_id = b.occurr_id
join tbl_policies c on a.id_police = c.id_police
left join tbl_Agreements d on a.id_police  = d.id_police
union
select
case_id,
a.id_police,
c.sign_date,
d.sign_date as sign_date2,
e.id_condition,
from loss.tbl_Insurance_Cases a 
join loss.tbl_Occurrences b on a.occurr_id = b.occurr_id
join tbl_policies c on a.id_police = c.id_police
left join tbl_Agreements d on a.id_police  = d.id_police
join tbl_InsuranceConditions e on c.id_conditions = e.id_condition
```

Comment: union all тогда уж))

Comment: Если нужны дублирующиеся строки, тогда можно и union all.

Answer (score 0):

Уточните СУБД, которую используете.
А так по классике можно примерно так:

```
select
  case_id,
  a.id_police,
  c.sign_date,
  d.sign_date as sign_date2,
  case 
    when Tp.tp = 1 
    then d.id_condition
    else e.id_condition
  end as id_condition
from loss.tbl_Insurance_Cases a 
  join loss.tbl_Occurrences b on a.occurr_id = b.occurr_id
  join tbl_policies c on a.id_police = c.id_police
  left join tbl_Agreements d on a.id_police  = d.id_police
  join tbl_InsuranceConditions e on c.id_conditions = e.id_condition
  cross join (select 1 as tp union all select 2)as Tp(tp)
```

Суть в том что соединяем со сгенерированной табличкой с двумя строками (1),(2) - а потом в зависимости от значения выбираем нужный Ид